# What are proofs for brahman?

Tags: brahman

I want to know if there are any proofs or books I can read that prove brahman exists?preferably of the advaita variety,but dvaita is also good.

how do I know shunyata isnt true above brahman?any books I can read on this topic?

Comment: Whether Brahman exists or God exists, books cant prove it to you, otherwise even parrots who can cram hymns of Vedas or scriptures would have been enlightened. Only proof of Brahman is you yourself as Brahman is not some bookish theory but practicality. An animal believes only in concrete and what it perceives but subtle Brahman is the cause of perception and thats why man is given intellect that separates it from animals and with which he can discriminate and understand the cause of perception.Brahman, Shunyata, God etc.,these are all just words and will perish in time,but present is eternal.

Comment: you yourself is the proof who makes you to grow when younger, who is programming you to become older and die is this change in your control same holds for the whole universe observe yourself when you are sick you are not able to walk upright who is making you walkupright lets us assume all this are chemical reactions then question arise why the reaction is programmed to work in this way? same for earth, moon and sun.

Comment: Proving Brahman is beyond a human's capacity.  Can any one prove what LOVE look like?  ABSTRACT things can only be experienced.  In my opinion, the question is off-topic, as the answers would be opinion based.

Comment: There are no proofs. According to Hinduism faith is the proof.

Comment: @Wikash_ False. You don't understand the real essence of Hinduism then, only the faith projection of it which is easier to digest.

Comment: @Weezy Well, if you have concrete proof go to the Nobel prize committee,

Comment: @Wikash_ Sorry to inform you but Nobel prizes aren't handed out for philosophy or theology since, forever. I stand by what I said. You are mistaken when you say there is no proof. It's not something objective that can be proven with conventional methods so it is wrong of you to ask me that. The proof is experiential and intuitive, subtle and ineffable. If you cannot prove it to yourself, I'm not sure anybody can. Scriptures are only guides. They are not set in stone. Yet we take them on authority only because they've stood the test of time in providing helpful pointers. Hope that clears up.

Comment: @Weezy nice story. Nobel prizes are given for prestigious research. I am sure if you write a nice report with concrete proof you can win it. "Yet we take them on authority only " I am also an authority. Why would you not believe me then? "Scriptures are only guides." I am also a guide.

Comment: @Wikash_ Sorry again, but you don't understand, proofs per say don't qualify as a NP candidate and I'm worried I have to tell you this. Look at Einstein, he won it for not relativity, which still stands to date the most tested classical theory, but for an experimentally verified result. Doesn't matter if your theory is consistent, NP committee couldn't care less. Also you seem to be bent on defending your stance which is incorrect. Be wise and accept that Hinduism has always privileged logic and reason over blind faith. Many discussions on here are witness to that.

Comment: @Wikash_ The majority of Hindu movement might be faith based traditions and culture, but at its core, it's the philosophy of consciousness, a theory of mind. Look beyond the metaphors and you may find it too. I'm not here to lecture you, but I will disagree that statement "according to Hinduism faith is the proof" holds any truth.

Comment: @Weezy Hinduism is called a religion. It is not science based. It mostly consists of scriptures which are mythology. Of course you need experimentally verified results but that should be possible since you apparently know how to recognize the brahman. Just take 2 groups and perform a double blinded study. Hinduism also consists of a lot of sects which disagree among each other about the metaphors and hyoptheses of the mind. The statements in the sciptures remain unverified to this day. I hope to see concrete proof one day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104690/discussion-between-wikash-and-weezy).

Answer (score 1):

there are probably millions of words written about Nirvana/brahman/samadhi.  All these words are totally useless unless you directly experience what lies beyond the extinguishment of the self.

To a modern seeker - J Krishnamurti's words are among the most accessible:  he says the same thing over and over again, using slightly different formulations each time -  but even they are only a pointer.  There seems to be no cookbook that will take you to brahman.

from [kinfornet.org](http://www.kinfonet.org/krishnamurti/quotes/every-struggle-every-effort-to-attain-liberation-i):

> As I said, liberation is not an end, it is not a goal; it is the understanding of right values, eternal values. Intelligence is ever becoming, it has no end, no finality. In the desire to attain there is a subtle craving for self-continuance, glorified self-continuance; and every struggle, every effort to attain liberation indicates an escape from the present. This summation of intelligence, which is liberation, is not to be understood through effort. After all, you make an effort when you want, when you desire to acquire something. But liberation is not to be acquired, truth is not to be acquired. So where there is a craving for liberation, for a culmination, for attainment, there must be an effort to sustain, to preserve, to perpetuate that consciousness which we call the "I". The very essence of that "I" is an effort to reach a culmination, because it lives in a series of movements of memory, moving towards an end.

Answer (score 1):

> What are proofs for brahman?

**According to Vedanta, Brahman can only be known through scriptural statements about it.**

Scripture here means *Vedas* and all other texts (Smritis) that are based on the Vedas.

---

In Hinduism, there are only 3 sources of knowledge: pratyaksha (perception), anumana (logic/inferences), and shabda (verbal testimony).

The existence of Brahman cannot be known from perception and inference, but only from verbal testimony of scripture.

The third sutra of the Brahma Sutras says:

> Because Scripture is the source (of the knowledge of Brahman).

And the medieval scholar Ramanujacharya comments on that sutra:

> Because Brahman, being raised above all contact with the senses, is not an object of perception and the other means of proof, **but to be known through Scripture only**; therefore the [Vedic verse] "Whence these creatures are born, ..." etc., has to be accepted as instructing us regarding the true nature of Brahman.

He then goes on to refute the cosmological arguments for Brahman propounded by the Nyaya and Vaisheshika schools, which believe that Brahman can be proved through inference.